# How to position an image above the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position, absolute

I am trying to position an image above (NOT before) the text. Below is the code I have so far. I also posted the result I am getting and the one I want to achieve. My goal is, when the user hover the `<p>` I want to show an image above it, this mean I need to use absolute position because I do not want anything to be shifted anywhere else, I just want to show the image above the text.

**NOTE: The image has no define height, it could be longer or shorter.**

```
 <div id="wrap" style="position:relative; height: 100px; width: 500px; background: red">
        <img src="img/cat.png" style="position:absolute; ">
        <p style="position:absolute; ">Some text here..</p>
</div>
```

This is the result I get,

[image]

This is my desire result. Note: I DON't want anything to be shifted, I just want to show the image above the text once it is hovered therefore I do not need anything to be shifted anywhere.

[image]

Comment: give `z-index:1000000;` in style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Rhcp5/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
        <img src="img/cat.png">
        <p>Some text here..</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap {
position:relative; 
height: 100px; 
width: 500px; 
background: red;
}

#wrap img {
display: none;
position: absolute;
bottom: 100%;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#wrap:hover img {
display: block;
}
```

This will handle images of variable height.

Comment: Look at my reply to David Aguirre, you posted the same answer

Comment: Try it and see. It is not the same answer. It handles images of variable height.

Answer (score 0):

Give the container "wrap" a position of "relative"
Then position the image as you are now with "absolute" then use negative "top"

```
<div id="wrap" style="position:relative; height: 100px; width: 500px; background: red">
    <img src="img/cat.png" style="position:absolute; ">
    <p style="position:absolute; ">Some text here..</p>
</div>
```

heres the css

```
#wrap {
    position: relative;
}

#wrap img:hover {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    left: 0;
}
```

if you do not know the height of the image then use Jquery. Not tested.

```
var imageHeight = $("#imgID").height();
$('#imgID').hover(function() {
    $('#imgID').css({
       'position': 'absolute',
       'top': '-' + imageHeight,
       'right': '0'
    }) 
});
```

Comment: This would work but what if the image is so large in height, then the top: -50px will be useless. Like I said, the image has no define height

Comment: Well you should not let the image exceed a specific height. Use the "max-height" for your images so they do not exceed a certain height.

Comment: true, but if I set the max-height lets say to 100px, and the image is lower than 100px like 40px, then the image will be far away to the text.

Comment: added some JQuery that should fix the issue. Not tested though, however it should work.